# VMware have network access but can't ping anywhere

Tags: vmware, nat, icmp

I am using VMware 9.0.0 on a Windows 7(64bits) host, the guest OS is CentOS 6.5(I have tried Ubuntu 12.04 also).

Firewall on Windows 7 is completely disabled. My host is connected to a router via wireless network adapter.

Guest's network configuration is NAT, and guest IP address is 192.168.117.130. Default gateway of the guest is 192.168.117.2. The Nat Interface(VMware Network Adapter VMnet8) on Windows 7 have an IP address of 192.168.117.1.

The problem I met is that I can have Internet access, actually, every network service using TCP and UDP is ok. But I can't ping any host other than hosts on the network of 192.168.17.0/24.

I used wireshark to locate the problem. I found a strange phenomenon, my host can receive the ping echo request from the guest and ping echo response, but it is not forwarding to the guest. Seems the NAT of ICMP packet is not working.

Any suggestions?